# JavaFX Spinner - this same keyevent to more spinner

Tags: java, javafx

I have a little problem. I want to use this code for two spinner and I can not handle it. Thank you for your help

```
        spinner1.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case UP:
                spinner1.increment(1);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                spinner1.decrement(1);
                break;
            default:
        }
    });
        spinner2.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case UP:
                spinner2.increment(1);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                spinner2.decrement(1);
                break;
            default:
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to reuse the same handler instance, or do you just want to avoid repeating the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single `EventHandler` instance ,

```
 EventHandler eh = (EventHandler<KeyEvent>) event -> {
      Spinner sp = (Spinner) event.getSource();
      switch (event.getCode()) {
          case UP:
              sp.increment(1);
              break;
          case DOWN:
              sp.decrement(1);
              break;
          default:
      }
  };

 spinner1.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(eh);
 spinner2.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(eh);
```

Comment: This results in a `ClassCastException`, since the source is not the spinner, but the `TextField`. You could traverse the scene graph up until you find a spinner though... Furthermore you do not need to use the cast for the lambda, if you use the parametrized type on the LHS.